# How to display LIVE time with specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a live time on my website, but with a specific timezone (GMT-4, Toronto). Since my javascript knowledge is minimal, I tried googling for a solution but it's difficult to understand. I took a look at luxon.js but not sure how to work with it. I found a snippet of code that displays current system time but not sure what to do with it. any help would be appreciated!

```
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toLocaleTimeString` method that already exists in the Date object if you just want to show the current time.
Then update it using setInterval of 1 minute (+60*1000ms), if you want the precision of 1 minute or 1000ms for the precision of 1 second.

```js
setInterval(() => {
const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    hour12: true,
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    timeZone: 'America/Toronto'
   });
console.log(date);
}, 1000);
```

Documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Comment: Since Toronto has daylight saving, it might be better to use a specific offset of -0400 (or perhaps -0500 for standard time). And the language code should probably be "en-CA". ;-) And since *setInterval* is not exact, the displayed time will skip a second occasionally.